# Spring Boot Listener for database connection failures

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

Is there a listener or interceptor that I can use to be notified when my application looses connection to my database? If I turn off the database as my application is running I get a log statement for it.

```
"HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3cb8289f (This connection has been closed.).
```

Ive tried to use the `ConnectionEventListener` but that didn't seem to work.

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class JDBCConnectionListener implements ConnectionEventListener {
    @Override
    public void connectionClosed(ConnectionEvent event) {
        log.error("connection closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionErrorOccurred(ConnectionEvent event) {
        log.error("connection error");
    }
}
```

Im using SpringBoot, JPA/Hibernate, and liquibase. My repositories extend `CrudRepository`.